# ToolBar not visible in 9930 simulator

Tags: blackberry, toolbar

I've added a bottom toolbar using a `ToolbarManager` which shows in the 9800 and 9520(which have a similar screen size) simulator but not in the 9930 simulator. I haven't tested this on an actual 9930 and do not currently have a way to do so either, but this behavior is weird so far. I've used the standard code given on BB dev site:

```
bottomBar = new ToolbarManager();
bottomBar.add(new ToolbarButtonField(ImageFactory.createImage(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a.png")), new StringProvider("Button 1"));
//------------------more buttons and other fields------------------------//
setToolbar(bottomBar);
```

What could be the reason why it isn't visible?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console about not being about to layout the field?

Comment: nope...just a couple of warnings about unnecessary variables

Comment: @tipycalflow: rotate your emulator horizontally and check whether your toolbar is visible or not.

Comment: The simulator doesn't support orientations by default and I don't know how to do that programmatically :(

Comment: @tipycalFlow I mean when it's running, not during compile time. Sometimes you'll have a field not lay out properly and it'll mention it in the console when you get to that view.

Comment: I did mean when the simulator was running :). In fact, I checked this with the debugger. If someone could reproduce this problem at their end too, it might help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue with Bold devices (e.g. 9900, 9930, 9790) that they don't have a toolbar even though `ToolbarManager.isToolbarSupported()` returns true.